# Affectiva/Affdex SDK video file analysis error in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, affdex-sdk

I have an app which records the video in the background and after a button click, the Affdex API analyzes the recorded video files stored. The application is behaving weirdly where it works the first time, but gives the following error later:

Note: I am not recording any audio while the video is being recorded

> 06-01 17:41:16.010 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder E/Affectiva: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   06-01 17:41:16.052 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
>   06-01 17:41:16.062 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
>   06-01 17:41:16.064 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
>   06-01 17:41:16.068 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
>   06-01 17:41:16.069 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
>   06-01 17:41:16.071 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
>   06-01 17:41:16.072 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
>   06-01 17:41:16.075 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
>   06-01 17:41:16.086 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
>   06-01 17:41:16.089 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
>   06-01 17:41:16.090 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ffmpeg
>   06-01 17:41:16.090 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/dts
>   06-01 17:41:16.092 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
>   06-01 17:41:16.092 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
>   06-01 17:41:16.093 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
>   06-01 17:41:16.094 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
>   06-01 17:41:16.095 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
>   06-01 17:41:16.099 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vnd.rn-realvideo
>   06-01 17:41:16.100 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
>   06-01 17:41:16.101 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/ffmpeg
>   06-01 17:41:16.102 6829-8352/com.sample.camerarecorder W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
>   06-01 17:41:16.104 6829-8481/com.sample.camerarecorder I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
>   06-01 17:41:16.161 6829-8480/com.sample.camerarecorder I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 6992898
>   06-01 17:41:16.161 6829-8481/com.sample.camerarecorder W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.h264.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
>   06-01 17:41:16.161 6829-8481/com.sample.camerarecorder E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the demo application : https://github.com/Affectiva/android-sdk-samples

Comment: Yeah I followed the steps mentioned in that application itself.

Comment: any luck figuring this out?